# Разгадывание капчи с картинки??? Xevil

Tags: captcha, xevil

Отправляю капчу на разгадывание из зеннопостера. Капчу отправляю картинкой, эмуляция в Xevil идет нормально, а дальше затык.

[image: скриншот]

Подскажите, как исправить данный вопрос и заставить xevil принимать эту капчу?

Comment: Уважаемый! Вот скажите, ваш вопрос хоть как то информирует нас и будущих читателей о проблеме? Он самодостаточен? Допустим такую ситуацию: У меня заблокирован сайт ibb.co, как мне вам помочь? Я не вижу в вопросе самой ошибки, что вы получаете, что вы хотите и так далее. Сделайте вопрос более информативный и самодостаточный! Изображение должно быть как дополнение, а не как основа вопроса! Теперь по поводу проблемы, так вам же сразу пишут "неверный формат URI". Бывают ли адреса вида `captcha?type=**`? Нет, ибо правильный формат - `http://site.ru/captcha?type=**`.

Comment: Теги некорректные, при чём тут c#? Поменял на ZennoPoster. Чисто академически это всё-таки можно считать за программирование, так что вопрос тематичен. И не сказать как обычно прикладывайте код картинкой, да и "код" вроде как приведён... Так что формальных оснований для закрытия вопроса не вижу: пусть живёт, вдруг кто-нибудь даже заинтересуется таким курьёзом и даст ответ.

Comment: Вместо того чтобы ругаться, напишите по человечески какая информация вам необходима для полноценного ответа. Я не имею желания переливать из пустого в порожнее.

Comment: по поводу вопросов в первом посте: 1. получаю, при отсылке капчи в виде картинки на ксевил, следующий ответ: wrong answer - невозможно определить формат uri - все, никаких пояснений больше тут нет, Могу сам код отправки привести. Нужно? Так будет более информативно.

Comment: по поводу адреса каптчи - все верно указано, ошибка в коде, а не в адресе url капчи возникает